# API.AI - How to authenticate user with Gmail account OR Active directory in chat bot

Tags: dialogflow-es

We are developing a chat bot for finance.

So once user going to start chat, bot should prompt for login. Then Once click on login, user should be redirected for login form and able to login with correct credentials, and bot should able to understand that user authentication succeeded or failed.

We are going to use our own custom platform(Agent page) i.e html page to communicate with api.ai.

Please provide info, if any one has done similar stuff or how to accomplish it.

Comment: You don't need to perform login through chatbot,right? So you can perform login as traditional service and after login start the chat. In each interaction with chatbot you will have token/cookie of user session. Facebook and Google Home offer "Account linking api" to secure and login user on enterprise site in which the services are called by chatbot on their platform.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand it the recommendation is to pop up a browser window for the authentication (with the correct auth url for the service you want the user to auth against) and then store the access token in the bot's state/db for this conversation.
Have a look at for example https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tsmatsuz/2016/09/06/microsoft-bot-framework-bot-with-authentication-and-signin-login/, should give you some ideas.

Answer (score -1):

Well, since it's a finace chatbot developer, I can try to give out what I know. I would advise that the chatbot should be on a different website. I'm saying this because if a person fails the login form and user credentials,the chatbot can actually teach the person how to do it, what his or her mistakes were, and how to correct them. if people see this and it's easier,they will pay more interest into your website. Or if that doesn't work, the user should be directed to a Facebook page,or an agent page.